# BBC: "Man convicted of murdering his girlfriend and their 10-month-old daughter at Winchester Crown Court"

Tags: grammar

What do you make of the following BBC News headline:

> Man convicted of murdering his girlfriend and their 10-month-old daughter at Winchester Crown Court

Is it just me, or does this read as if the murders were committed at the court?

Comment: Squad helps dog bite victim.

Comment: Two sisters reunite after eighteen years at checkout counter

Comment: Wait, so the murders *weren't* committed at Winchester Crown Court?

Comment: Sometimes I think that the BBC staff quite likes trying to sneak little grammatical jokes into the fix.  They're pretty good at subversive picture captions, too.

Comment: The proper name for these is "crash blossoms": http://www.crashblossoms.com/

Comment: Well this is the **Eats, Shoots and Leaves** thing isn't it?

Comment: Police murder suspect in court.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. The meaning is understood, but a decent editor would have dropped the place reference from the headline. It adds nothing and introduces ambiguity.

To recast the sentence for clarity, I would suggest:

> Man convicted at Winchester Crown
>   Court of murdering his girlfriend and
>   their 10-month-old daughter

That puts the money words ("murdering" "girlfriend" "daughter") at too far a remove from the beginning of the headline, however, so it is easy to see why the editor chose to put the place reference at the end. As I say, however, this information seems to belong more in body copy than in a headline.

Comment: But that puts "murder", an even better attention grabber than "convicted", farther from the beginning of the page. Grammar loses to marketing.

Comment: We could argue about the best way to phrase the headline. I merely offered one idea. Still, one could argue that the man was not legally a murderer until convicted. Moreover, if you use up that provocative word as a noun, what are you going to use for the much more important verb? "Murderer convicted ... of killing ... "? Sounds anticlimactic to me.

Comment: I agree with Sparr that "Man convicted of murdering…" is more attention-holding than "Man convicted at Winchester Crown Court…". If you could use "murderer", then of course you could write "Murderer of girlfriend and 10-month-old daughter convicted at Winchester Crown Court", which is perhaps even better.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible headline would be "Winchester Crown Court convicts man of murdering his girlfriend and their 10-month-old daughter".  I agree, though, that mentioning the court at all seems quite unnecessary.

Comment: Agreed! -------

Answer (score 1):

No, you and many other people choose to ignore the rules of implicature. and wilfully misinterpret the sentence, for comic effect.